# Responsively moving text inside of a div

Tags: css

My question is quite simple but I've been struggling with it for quite some time.

https://jsfiddle.net/txzk0ffm/

```css
body {
  width:100%;
}
h1{
  margin:0;
}
.box-wrap {
  width:70%;
  background:red;
  height:350px;
}
.text-wrap {
  width:35%;
  position:relative;
  top:25%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrap"style="background:red url(http://www.saadiyat.ae/Admin/Content/banner-img-3.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;">
  <div class="img-wrap" >
    <div class="text-wrap">
      <h1>
        Random text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to move the box with text with use of % by using things like

```
top:50%;
bottom:30%;
etc.
```

I tried to use position relative, but nothing seems to be happening

Comment: You want background for text only? am I right?

Comment: Do you want to keep the text at center of the content? Why use %?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/21rzs17t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent height is `auto`, so you can't use percentage as vertical mesurment inside of it.

You need to add

```
.img-wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
```

to solve the problem:

```css
h1{
  margin:0;
}
.box-wrap {
  width:70%;
  background:red;
  height:350px;
}
.text-wrap {
  width:35%;
  position:relative;
  top:25%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.img-wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrap"style="background:red url(http://www.saadiyat.ae/Admin/Content/banner-img-3.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;">
  <div class="img-wrap" >
    <div class="text-wrap">
      <h1>
        Random text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been using usually height auto, for most of the things. It could be a problem, It is cause I hate work on hard pixels x_ x

Answer (score 0):

Specify a **fixed** `height` to the parent and it works :

```
.text-wrap {
  height: 350px;
}

.text-wrap h1{
  width:35%;
  position:relative;
  top:25%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txzk0ffm/2/)

Comment: Hate this way. Why are so many people using px-values in places where they are not required??

Comment: Because I didn't know an other way of doing it, I recognize your answer is better so you have my upvote but I still let my answer because it's an other way of doing it.
Furthermore, OP use a fixed height for the box-wrap as well.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you mean than you have to give your `.box-wrap{ position: relative;}` and your `.text-wrap{ position: absolute;}`

```css
body {
  width:100%;
}
h1{
  margin:0;
}
.box-wrap {
  width:70%;
  background:red;
  height:350px;
  position:relative;
}
.text-wrap {
  width:35%;
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrap"style="background:red url(http://www.saadiyat.ae/Admin/Content/banner-img-3.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;">
  <div class="img-wrap" >
    <div class="text-wrap">
          <h1>
            Random text
          </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please change your css for text-wrap class with following :-

```
.text-wrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Height of the img-wrap]

Your text-wrap has its position relative to the `img-wrap`, which itself has exactly the same height as the `text-wrap`.

The simplest solution is to give the `img-wrap` the height of the `box-wrap`:

```
.img-wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
```